# Optimize or rewrite pivot query that uses multiple common table expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, pivot

I need help optimizing or rewriting this complex query. The query worked great with the test data that had 50 rows but the real data now has over 700,000 rows and the query takes over five minutes to run. I have indexes on the primary keys of the two tables. I believe the age function is a lot of the cost as if I take it out it saves about 2 ½ minutes. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks In advance.

```
WITH T AS (
        SELECT TOP 2000
          A.Residence_City, 
          CASE 
             WHEN A.Gender = 'M' then 'Male'
             WHEN A.Gender = 'F' then 'Female'
             WHEN A.Gender = 'U' then 'Unknown'
        END AS Gender,
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 18 and 24 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_18],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 18 and 24 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_18],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 18 and 24 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_18],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 18 and 24 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_18],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 18 and 24 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_18],

count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 25 and 34 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_25],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 25 and 34 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_25],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 25 and 34 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_25],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 25 and 34 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_25],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 25 and 34 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_25],

count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 35 and 49 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_35],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 35 and 49 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_35],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 35 and 49 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_35],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 35 and 49 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_35],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 35 and 49 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_35],

count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 50 and 64 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_50],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 50 and 64 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_50],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 50 and 64 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_50],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 50 and 64 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_50],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 50 and 64 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_50],

count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 65 and 120 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_65],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 65 and 120 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_65],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 65 and 120 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_65],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 65 and 120 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_65],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) between 65 and 120 and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_65],

count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) = '' or voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() )is null and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [0_3_],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) = '' or voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() )is null and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 1 then 1 else null end) as [1_3_],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) = '' or voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() )is null and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 2 then 1 else null end) as [2_3_],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) = '' or voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() )is null and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 3 then 1 else null end) as [3_3_],
count(case when voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) = '' or voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge ( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() )is null and voterData.dbo.GeneralVoting (V.[G10EC], V.[G08EC],V.[G06EC]) = 0 then 1 else null end) as [Unknown_]

from Personal as A INNER JOIN Voting_History V 
on A.Vuid = V.Vuid 
group by Residence_City, Gender with rollup
Order by Residence_City, Gender 
)
, temp1 as (
    SELECT  *,([3_3_18] + [3_3_25] + [3_3_35] + [3_3_50] + [3_3_65] + [3_3_]
              +[2_3_18] + [2_3_25] + [2_3_35] + [2_3_50] + [2_3_65] + [2_3_]
              +[1_3_18] + [1_3_25] + [1_3_35] + [1_3_50] + [1_3_65] + [1_3_]
              +[0_3_18] + [0_3_25] + [0_3_35] + [0_3_50] + [0_3_65] + [0_3_]
            +[Unknown_18]+ [Unknown_25]+ [Unknown_35] + [Unknown_50]+ [Unknown_65] + [Unknown_]) Total
FROM T
where NULLIF(Residence_City,'') IS NOT NULL
), temp2 as (
    SELECT * FROM temp1
UNION ALL
select 
'grand Total',
SUM([0_3_18])/2,SUM([1_3_18])/2,SUM([2_3_18])/2,SUM([3_3_18])/2,SUM([Unknown_18])/2,
SUM([0_3_25])/2,SUM([1_3_25])/2,SUM([2_3_25])/2,SUM([3_3_25])/2,SUM([Unknown_25])/2,
SUM([0_3_35])/2,SUM([1_3_35])/2,SUM([2_3_35])/2,SUM([3_3_35])/2,SUM([Unknown_35])/2,
SUM([0_3_50])/2,SUM([1_3_50])/2,SUM([2_3_50])/2,SUM([3_3_50])/2,SUM([Unknown_50])/2,
SUM([0_3_65])/2,SUM([1_3_65])/2,SUM([2_3_65])/2,SUM([3_3_65])/2,SUM([Unknown_65])/2,
SUM([0_3_])/2,SUM([1_3_])/2,SUM([2_3_])/2,SUM([3_3_])/2,SUM([Unknown_])/2,
sum(Total)/2

FROM temp1
)

SELECT Residence_City, Gender,
    [0_3_18]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_18]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_18]     as [2_3], 
    [3_3_18]     as [3_3], 
    [Unknown_18] as [Unknown],

    [0_3_25]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_25]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_25]     as [2_3],  
    [3_3_25]     as [3_3],  
    [Unknown_25] as [Unknown], 

    [0_3_35]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_35]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_35]     as [2_3], 
    [3_3_35]     as [3_3], 
    [Unknown_35] as [Unknown], 

    [0_3_35]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_35]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_35]     as [2_3], 
    [3_3_35]     as [3_3], 
    [Unknown_35] as [Unknown], 

    [0_3_35]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_35]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_35]     as [2_3], 
    [3_3_35]     as [3_3], 
    [Unknown_35] as [Unknown], 

    [0_3_35]     as [0_3],  
    [1_3_35]     as [1_3], 
    [2_3_35]     as [2_3], 
    [3_3_35]     as [3_3], 
    [Unknown_35] as [Unknown], 
    Total
   FROM temp2
```

These are the functions

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GeneralVoting] ( @one varchar, @two varchar,@three varchar)
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @vAge         INT

        SET @vAge = (CASE WHEN @one IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        +(CASE WHEN @two IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        +(CASE WHEN @three IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     RETURN @vAge
    END
```

And

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetAge] ( @pDateOfBirth DATETIME, @pAsOfDate DATETIME )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @vAge         INT
        IF @pDateOfBirth >= @pAsOfDate
            RETURN 0

        SET @vAge = DATEDIFF(YY, @pDateOfBirth, @pAsOfDate)

        IF MONTH(@pDateOfBirth) > MONTH(@pAsOfDate) OR
          (MONTH(@pDateOfBirth) = MONTH(@pAsOfDate) AND
           DAY(@pDateOfBirth)   > DAY(@pAsOfDate))
            SET @vAge = @vAge - 1
      RETURN @vAge
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join structures seem reasonable.  I'm not sure if you need the rollup, but it probably does not affect performance.

I suspect the user defined functions are affecting performance.  SQL Server is not smart enough to optimize away the multiple calls to ufn_GetAge(), so the function gets called over and over.  Instead, put the age in a subquery:

```
(select *, voterData.dbo.ufn_GetAge( convert(datetime,[Date_of_Birth]), GETDATE() ) as age
 from VoterData
) age
```

The function is pretty simple, so you could also replace it in-line to eliminate this one call.

You can take the same approach for the other function as well.

Also, how large are the Voting and Personal History tables?  In particular, how many combinations of city and gender?  You might be able to make the query more efficient by pre-selecting the top 2000 and then doing the calculations for the different groups.  Without knowing the sizes, though, it is hard to tell whether this works.  Also, do you really mean to order by Residence_City, Gender . . . or do you want to order by one of the other fields?  As is, the query just selects the first  alphabetically.

Comment: Both tables have about 45 columns each, there are 31 different cities and 3 gender combinations. The top 2000 should actually be top 1,000,000 because the query should take all records into account.For the ordering, It really doesn't matter. I am trying the subquery suggestion right now, Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Your suggestions got the query down to 22 seconds. HUGE improvement, Thanks for your time.